# が in the expression "耳が聞こえない"

Tags: particles, expressions, particle-が, phrases, potential-form

I tried to translate this phrase literally and came up with "(My) ears can't hear". Since the expression means "(I'm) deaf", this makes sense.
However, I can't really get it to work grammatically, seeing as が isn't normally used to denote the subject in sentences with a "potential"-form.
So how can が be grammatically explained in this expression?
Thanks for reading through my question.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21516/9831

Comment: _" が isn't normally used to denote the subject in sentences with a "potential"-form."_  Hernh?  This is news to me.  What particle do you expect for these potential constructions?

Comment: @chocolate In the link to goo in the link you gave, a definition of 見える was 見ることができる. This was new and surprising to me. But when I looked up 聞こえる in goo, I didn't see the definition 聞くことができる. I'm really bad with Japanese dictionaries, so maybe I missed it. Presumably that is also a valid definition? Does 耳が聞けない sound wrong? Why use 耳が聞こえない?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I thought it was most common to either omit the subject entirely or instead mark it with に, は, or には.

Comment: @user3856370 ほんとですねぇ・・ 「見える -- ２ 見ることができる」はあるのに、「聞こえる -- 聞くことができる」はないですねぇ。。　We say 「猫は暗闇でも(目が)見える」「目が見えない」「耳が聞こえる・耳が聞こえない」, not「耳が聞ける・聞けない」「目が見られる・見られない」... 明鏡国語辞典には「聞こえる -- 耳で感じ取ることができる。...『耳が聞こえる(=聴覚能力がある)』」とありますが…

Comment: @Chocolate 新明解国語辞典には「聞こえる -- 音･声が（自然に）耳に感じられる」とあるのですが、その文法欄に『「聞こえる」は、普通の聴力のある人なら、適度な音量があり、しかもほかの音や声に妨げられることがなければ、自然に耳に達する状態を表わす』と補足しています。これを読んで「耳が聞こえる＝聴力がある」と解釈できなくもないと私は思いますが、どうでしょうか。